# Entropy of Weilbull Distribution

Tags: probability, information-theory, entropy

I have a hard integral that I would like to compute. As the tittle suggests, I'm interested in the Weibull distribution. For $k,\lambda >0$ its distribution function is given by:

$$f(x)= \frac{k}{\lambda}\bigg(\frac{x}{\lambda}\bigg)^{k-1}\exp\bigg[-\bigg(\frac{x}{\lambda}\bigg)^k\bigg]$$

I'm interested in computing its entropy, i.e.

$$-\int_0^{\infty} \frac{k}{\lambda}\bigg(\frac{x}{\lambda}\bigg)^{k-1}\exp\bigg[-\bigg(\frac{x}{\lambda}\bigg)^k\bigg] \ln \bigg\{ \frac{k}{\lambda}\bigg(\frac{x}{\lambda}\bigg)^{k-1}\exp\bigg[-\bigg(\frac{x}{\lambda}\bigg)^k\bigg]\bigg\}dx$$

All the usual techniques seem to fail, like integration by parts or substitution. I tried for instance setting $z:=(x/k)^{k-1}$ but it does not seem to lead anywhere. What can be some useful trick for this task?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Edited @ClaudeLeibovici

Comment: Consider expanding the $\ln(a . b)$ factor into $\ln a + \ln b$, giving two simpler integrals...

Comment: Have done that, but the expressions remain complex... @JeanMarie

Comment: The second integral is definitely not complex !!!

Comment: The exponent is missing a $-$ sign.

Comment: Just in case, the result can be found in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution

Comment: Edited @J.G. thanks

Comment: I see, thanks @leonbloy

Comment: @JeanMarie I have managed to do the second integral. Any tips on the first one? :)

Comment: Do you mean (with the change of variable $X=x/\lambda$), integral : $\int_0^{\infty} k X^{k-1}e^{-X^k} \ln(k X^{k-1})dx$ ?

Comment: Yeah! @JeanMarie Im trying to use integation by parts but I get something like $\log x$ evaluated at 0 which of course causes problems..

Comment: A rather difficult integral. Grouping the power and the logarithm could have been an idea, because setting $u=k X^{k-1}$, we get $u \ln(u)$ has a known primitive function $\frac12 u^2( \ln(u) - 1)$ but in fact the above change of variable brings in other complicated terms.

Comment: Done it! @JeanMarie